# Strapi: Middleware "strapi::body": Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'strapi.plugin(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: sqlite, content-management-system, middleware, strapi

I am trying to install a fresh Strapi app on my mac, by running the

```
npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart
```

commnand. It installs the Strapi app fine, but when I try to run "npm run develop", I get this error:

"Strapi: Middleware "strapi::body": Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'strapi.plugin(...)' as it is undefined."

And the app doesn't start. full error text is as follows:

```
 Middleware "strapi::body": Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'strapi.plugin(...)' as it is undefined.
Error: Middleware "strapi::body": Cannot destructure property 'config' of 'strapi.plugin(...)' as it is undefined.
    at instantiateMiddleware (/Users/davit/Github/my-project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/middleware.js:12:11)
    at resolveMiddlewares (/Users/davit/Github/my-project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/middleware.js:56:18)
    at registerApplicationMiddlewares (/Users/davit/Github/my-project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/register-middlewares.js:66:29)
    at async Object.initMiddlewares (/Users/davit/Github/my-project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/index.js:99:7)
    at async Strapi.bootstrap (/Users/davit/Github/my-project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:445:5)
    at async Strapi.load (/Users/davit/Github/my-project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:457:5)
    at async Strapi.start (/Users/davit/Github/my-project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:198:9)
```

Would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same exception when `yarn develop`.

1. Make sure you have right version range for `node`

   `node -v` if not use `nvm use 14.19.1` (or above)
2. Go to `package.json` and change strapi version.

   from `"@strapi/strapi": "^4.3.5"` to `"@strapi/strapi": "^4.3.6"`
3. Remove `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`
4. Run `npm install` or/and `yarn install`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think this method would've worked as well. 

I had also posted this question in Strapi forums and it turns out that the problem was with Strapi 4.3.5. They advised updating to 4.3.6 as this issue had been hotfixed. I can confirm that this issue no longer exists on Strapi 4.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had also posted this question in Strapi forums and it turns out that the problem was with Strapi 4.3.5. They advised updating to 4.3.6 as this issue had been hotfixed. I can confirm that this issue no longer exists on Strapi 4.3.6.